# How to Reset a Password

Tags: python, html, django

I have a custom form for forget password. please give me an idea about set a coding for forget password form.
Form is:-

```
<form action="/forgetpassword/" method="post" id="pass_form" style="display:none">
  <div class="top_b">Can't sign in?</div>    
  <div class="alert alert-info alert-login">
    Please enter your email address. You will receive a link to create a new password via email.
  </div>
  <div class="cnt_b">
    <div class="formRow clea00 Pesos durante un año (12 meses). Ver más.rfix">
      <div class="input-prepend">
        <span class="add-on">@</span><input type="text" placeholder="Your email address" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btm_b tac">
    <button class="btn btn-inverse" type="submit">Request New Password</button>
  </div>  
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django provides a mechanism for requesting a password reset. See [the password reset view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_reset) in the docs.